# Map Json array inside a Json React

Tags: reactjs

I have below JSON file. There is an Array(answers) inside that JSON. I want to map and render them.

```
    {
    "qID": "177",
    "myQuestion": true,
    "qContent": "testing",
    "answers": [{
            "anonymous": true,
            "aID": "184",
            "aContent": "test",
            "aDate": "Mon, 14 Sep 20 06:47:38 +0000",
            "myAnswer": false,
            "authorName": "abc",
            "aFeaturedImg": "..\/uploads\/407378vk053.jpg",
            "authorImg": "https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/a-\/AOh14GjhhO-11Wktws9-FXBZoWk3vT8tRM2Sy7IQ4cnpw=s96-c"
        },
        {
            "anonymous": true,
            "aID": "184",
            "aContent": "test",
            "aDate": "Mon, 14 Sep 20 06:47:38 +0000",
            "myAnswer": false,
            "authorName": "abc",
            "aFeaturedImg": "..\/uploads\/407378vk053.jpg",
            "authorImg": "https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/a-\/AOh14GjhhO-11Wktws9-FXBZoWk3Cv8tRM2Sy7IQ4cnpw=s96-c"
        }
    ]
}
```

my react code like this. I want to use state

function Question({ match }) {

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchItem();
}, []);

const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ qID: match.params.id })
};

const [item, setItem] = useState([]);



const fetchItem = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://example.com/api/getAnswer.php' , requestOptions);
    const item = await data.json();
    setItem(item);
    
         
};  


return (        
    <Container maxWidth="sm">
         
         {item.answers.map(answer => (
         <Card key={answer.qID}>{answer.qContent}</Card>
    ))}           
    </Container>
);
```

}

export default Question;
But This not work. It gives following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Comment: what you get for `console.log(item.answers)` just before the render? and is this json data coming from ajax? then how your `item` state looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't sure that the `answers` key of you data will considere as an array you can form javascript to considere it like that by passing it throught [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
let data = {
"qID": "177",
"myQuestion": true,
"qContent": "testing",
"answers": [{
        "anonymous": true,
        "aID": "184",
        "aContent": "test",
        "aDate": "Mon, 14 Sep 20 06:47:38 +0000",
        "myAnswer": false,
        "authorName": "abc",
        "aFeaturedImg": "..\/uploads\/407378vk053.jpg",
        "authorImg": "https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/a-\/AOh14GjhhO-11Wktws9-FXBZoWk3vT8tRM2Sy7IQ4cnpw=s96-c"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": true,
        "aID": "184",
        "aContent": "test",
        "aDate": "Mon, 14 Sep 20 06:47:38 +0000",
        "myAnswer": false,
        "authorName": "abc",
        "aFeaturedImg": "..\/uploads\/407378vk053.jpg",
        "authorImg": "https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/a-\/AOh14GjhhO-11Wktws9-FXBZoWk3Cv8tRM2Sy7IQ4cnpw=s96-c"
    }
]
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        let answers = Array.from(data.answers)
        
        return (<div>
            {answers.map(ans => {
                return <p>{ans.aContent}</p>
            })}
        </div>)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

As the `item` state can be an empty array before you get the data from the API, you can check It availability before performing map like this

```
return (        
    <Container maxWidth="sm">     
        {item.answers && item.answers.map(answer => (
             <Card key={answer.qID}>{answer.qContent}</Card>
        ))}           
    </Container>
);
```

`{item.answers && item.answers.map(answer => (...))}` this like check if `item.answers` exits before performing `map` on array of answers

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer. I want to implement this using state. I modified my question. can you help me?

Comment: You want the response to be save in your Component state and map the `answers` array which is hold in your component state

Comment: Hi. I tried following. But still gives an error.[code]const fetchItem = async () => {
        const data = await fetch('https://sith.lk/api/getAnswer.php' , requestOptions);
        const item = await data.json();
        setItem(item);
        const answers = Array.from(item.answers);
        setAnswers(answers);
             
    };  
    

    return (        
        <Container maxWidth="sm">             
             {answers.map(answer => (
             <Card key={answer.qID}>{answer.qContent}</Card>
        ))}           
        </Container>
    );

Comment: The data you provide in the question It's the way the response came back from the API's call

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if "item" contains valid value

```
{item && item.answers.map(answer => (
             <Card key={answer.aID}>{answer.aContent}</Card>
        ))}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. But this is not working.

Comment: try to hook item in useEffect useEffect(() => {
    fetchItem();
}, [item]);

Comment: did you also try to consol.log(item) inside fetchItem? to make sure you have the correct data

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your JSON into a javascript object, try doing this

```
let parsed_object = JSON.parse(item);
```

And then you can use `map` on the `parsed_object`.